# Spring MVC: JSP or JSON view in Controller method depending on request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Using @ResponseBody my controller returns a JSON representation of my pojo by default, but is possible to change the view to JSP by default, and return a JSON response only when your content type is `application/json`?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myRequest")
public @ResponseBody myPojo myRequest() throws Exception  {     
    return service.getMyPojo();
}
```

PS: I've tried `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`, but I'm not sure is the best one for achieving this.

Comment: This is exactly what `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` is for. Did you get it working?

Comment: No. I will try it. I've seen some examples online, but they weren't soing exactly this.

Answer (score 2):

You can have two mappings:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myRequest", headers="content-type=application/json")
public @ResponseBody jsonExample() throws Exception  {     
    return service.getMyPojo();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/myRequest", headers="content-type=text/*")
public String jspExample() throws Exception  {     
    return "myJspView";
}
```